# ErrorWidget for Flutter forms

Tags: flutter, material-design

I know that InputDecorator can be used to show a theme-colored error message by passing errorText.

What’s the best way to display a general error message above a form.

Is there a material error-widget or do I have to build it myself?

Comment: I've not seen such a widget, because honestly its just a text string visible on certain boolean with an error color above your form. You can simply write `condition ? Text("Error", style:TextStyle(color:Colors.red)):Container()`

Answer (score 0):

I am using this boilerplate now:

```
Text("Error message", style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(buildContext).errorColor))
```